# Calculate the facebook cover offset y

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I'm getting the user cover photo using Facebook SDK. I have the path to the img and the offset y.

```
  "source": "http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/526114_459046674110601_992101492_n.jpg",
  "offset_y": 19
```

The div where i put the image have 300px height; and right background position is `center -146px;`. How to calculate the `top value` when I have 300 and 19 ?

Comment: I really need help for this also. I got the same issue. I have offset_y 47 from FACEBOOK, and approx top -223 to fit the same image inside the div. The height of the div is 200px

Answer (score 0):

`offset_y` is a proportion of space between upper area and lower area of cropped image.

So, actual pixel offset should be like this:

```
y = (offset_y / 100) * (upperArea_of_cropImage.height + lowerArea_of_cropImage.height)
```

Edited:

```
// where y is the actual pixels from the upper left corner of the real image to
// upper left corner of the cropped image

        -- ================================  --
    y {   ||                              ||    } a
        --||..............................|| --
          ||                              ||
          ||                              ||
          ||            Cover             ||
          ||                              ||
          ||..............................|| --
          ||                              ||    } b
          ||                              ||   |
           ================================  --

     offset_y that Facebook send to you actually was a/b not y
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to use the offset?
I'm not sure I understand how knowing the proportion between the areas will help me find the top Y value of the cropped image.

Where do I get the upper/lowerArea_of_cropImage?

Thank you!

Comment: I really need help for this also. I got the same issue. I have offset_y 47 from FACEBOOK, and approx top -223 to fit the same image inside the div. The height of the div is 200px.

Comment: I edited my Answer.
(Maybe this is very very too late and Facebook maybe changed their APIs but just incase.)