# How to calculate Facebook cover offset

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to get some event cover images from Facebook and display them on my site. Now, people can upload images of various sizes and aspect ratios, and Facebook resizes it and allows them to center the image within a 784*295 frame. If you query Facebook API for cover image, this is what you get:

```
"cover": {
    "cover_id": 300822420082720,
    "offset_x": 0,
    "offset_y": 73,
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-9/10273881_300822420082715_6723919589261017620_n.jpg"
}
```

The "source" is a link to the original, non-resized/non-centered image. So I need to resize it/cut it in order for it to look exactly as the one the Facebook event page.

So the question is - **how do I apply offset_x/offset_y to get the same image like the one in the 784*295 Facebook frame?**

---

I have found following solutions, NONE of them correct:

- [offset_y - The vertical offset in pixels of the photo from the bottom.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event)
- [The offset that facebook sends is in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422301/1358631)
- [pixel_offset_y = (image_height-frame_height) * offset_y / 100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434804/1358631)
- [offset_y is a proportion of space between upper area and lower area of cropped image.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12197200/1358631)

I have tested all of this, and more, on a couple of cover images, one of them shown in picture below. The image below is 784*522 when resized (like Facebook does), the image frame is always 784*295, the offset_y I get is 73, and the distance from the top of the picture (measured on Facebook) is 193px. What I cannot get is how to use offset_y (73) to get the number of pixels offset from top (193).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK3k4.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end, I wasn't able to find an answer to this question anywhere, but I was able to achieve a satisfactory precision using an experimental method, that is, creating my own event and testing several cover pages by moving them a few pixels at a time. The formula to calculate the number of pixels of offset that need to be applied to the FB cover image in order to get the same frame as the one used in Facebook is as follows:

```
$pixelsFromAbove = (($imageHeight - $frameHeight) / 86 ) * $offset_y;
$pixelsFromLeft = (($imageWidth - $frameWidth) / 86 ) * $offset_y;
```

Frame height and width are 295 and 784 respectively. The "86" is the experimentally obtained magical number.

This solution works with the 2.1 version of FB API.

Answer (score 2):

Of the solutions you linked to above, the third is the closest to being 100% accurate (and may very well be for his use cases).

Here's how it worked out for me for event covers (change fw and fh for different types of covers).

You need:

**fw** - the width that Facebook displays the cover image
**fh** - the height that Facebook displays the cover image
**nw** - the natural width of the image retrieved from Facebook
**nh** - the natural height of the image retrieved from Facebook
**ow** - the width to which you're scaling the image down in your UI
**oy** - the offset_y value for the cover photo

The formula for the top offset (in pixels) is then:

**- (oy * ow / 100) * ((nh / nw) - (fh / fw))**

Here's how I implemented it in JavaScript:

```
self.changeOffsetY = function(element, eventCover) {
    if (eventCover === true) {
        var fw = 826;
        var fh = 294;
    } else {
        var fw = 828;
        var fh = 315;
    }

    var nw = element.naturalWidth;
    var nh = element.naturalHeight;
    var ow = element.offsetWidth;
    var oy = element.dataset.offsety;

    var top = (oy * ow / 100) * ((nh / nw) - (fh / fw));

    element.style.top = -top + 'px';
};
```

The formula is just a simplification of the algorithm.

Intuitively, you can understand it like this:

1. Cover photos are displayed in containers on Facebook. For event
   covers, they are currently 826x294 pixels.
2. When you upload an image and reposition it as high as you can, the offset_y value is 0.
3. When you reposition it as low as you can, the offset_y value is 100.
4. This means that the offset_y value is mapping 0 to 100 from half the container height (294/2 = 147), to the height of the image minus half the container height (height - 147).
5. For an image that's 1000px high with an offset_y of 25, the image will be centered along a horizontal line at 323.5px (147 + 25% of 706, which is the full height minus the Facebook container height), and will require a top value of -176.5px to match what you see on Facebook.
6. Of course, when you pull images from FB, they aren't as large, but they should be roughly proportional.
7. Also, you'll need to account for what size you'll be displaying the image, since the top positioning in CSS needs to be in pixels. Percents don't work because they'll be calculated based on the height of the container element.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to work on this trickery, and it took me a whole day! Although Knezmilos and Justin Harrisson previous answers helped me starting, I had to bang my head against the walls a couple of time before I finally got it working.

I used more than 2 000 real events to make sure each and every use case was ok, checking the final rendering was exactly the same on FB, as much as I can, and looks like my code is doing the job.

If you're a Rails users, good news for you, I extracted the hard stuff to a Gem: [facebook_cover_resize](https://github.com/gbarillot/facebook_cover_resize) . If you're using another stack and you're only interested by the raw algo, here it is (Ruby code, but you'll get the idea):

```
  ow = FINAL_OUTPUT_WIDTH.to_f
  oh = (ow / 1.91)
  nw = ORIGINAL_WIDTH.to_f
  nh = ORIGINAL_HEIGHT.to_f
  ox = OFFSET_X.to_f
  oy = OFFSET_Y.to_f

  if ox == 0 && oy == 0
    w = ow
    h = nh * (ow / nw)
    if h < oh
      h = oh
      w = nw * (oh / nh)
      offset_x = ow - w
      offset_y = 0
    else
      offset_x = 0
      if w < h
        offset_y = 0
      else
        offset_y = oh - h
      end
    end
  else
    if oy > 0
      w = ow
      h = nh * (ow / nw)
      offset_x = 0
      offset_y = (oh - h) * (oy / 100.0)
      if h < oh
        h = oh
        w = nw * (oh / nh)
        offset_x = (ow - w) / 2
        offset_y = 0
      end
    elsif ox > 0
      h = oh
      w = nw * (oh / nh)
      offset_x = (ow - w) / 2
      offset_y = 0
    else
      w = ow
      h = nh * (ow / nw)
      offset_x = 0
      offset_y = 0
    end
  end

  out = [
    offset_y.ceil,
    offset_x.ceil,
    w.ceil,
    h.ceil
  ]
```

Comment: Update on 2017/21/04: I made my Gem to also handle accounts cover image. Enjoy...